# SQL query to find superset role

Tags: sql, ms-access

We've got a system where users select a role from the service catalogue and the role is mapped to membership of some groups in the target system.

There is overlap of the groups across some roles and some roles are fulfilled by a group set that is a complete subset of another role.

It's the latter that's causing me a problem. I don't know how to extract the super set only.

```
Role Grps
Role1 GrpA
Role1 GrpB
Role1 GrpC
Role2 GrpA
Role2 GrpB
Role3 GrpA
Role3 GrpD

Usr Grps
User1 GrpA
User1 GrpB
User2 GrpA
User2 GrpB
User2 GrpC
User3 GrpA
User3 GrpD
User4 GrpD
```

Output required

```
Usr Role
User1 Role2
User2 Role1
User3 Role3
```

Rather than

```
Usr Role
User1 Role2
User2 Role1
User2 Role2
User3 Role3
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are we talking here? SQL Server?

Comment: I'm doing in MS Access

Comment: You may want to tag it with `ms-access`, Access supports a very limited subset of SQL, so an SQL solution may not help you very much.

Comment: So, essentially, you want a hierarchy of roles based on group membership?  This looks like it should be the same as one of those "find a user who has all tags" queries.  What do you have already - ie that's throwing out `User4`?

Comment: Yes, thats about it, though I want the top role from each strand of the hieracrchy.  All do now is count the groups per role in one query, essentially do the same in the users table and where thte two counts are the same there's a match...

Answer (score 1):

For test data in [tblRoleGrps]

```
Role   Grps
-----  ----
Role1  GrpA
Role1  GrpB
Role1  GrpC
Role2  GrpA
Role2  GrpB
Role3  GrpA
Role3  GrpD
```

and [tblUsrGrps]

```
Usr    Grps
-----  ----
User1  GrpA
User1  GrpB
User2  GrpA
User2  GrpB
User2  GrpC
User3  GrpA
User3  GrpD
User4  GrpD
```

we can create a saved query in Access named [qryRoleGrpCounts] that gives us the number of Groups that belong to each Role

```sql
SELECT Role, COUNT(*) AS GrpCount
FROM tblRoleGrps
GROUP BY Role
```

returning

```
Role   GrpCount
-----  --------
Role1         3
Role2         2
Role3         2
```

We can do the same thing for Users with a saved query named [qryUsrGrpCounts]

```sql
SELECT Usr, COUNT(*) AS GrpCount
FROM tblUsrGrps
GROUP BY Usr
```

returning

```
Usr    GrpCount
-----  --------
User1         2
User2         3
User3         2
User4         1
```

We can also create a query named [qryUsrRoleMatches] that counts the number of matches between Users and the Roles to which they *might* belong

```sql
SELECT ug.Usr, rg.Role, COUNT(*) AS MatchCount
FROM tblUsrGrps ug INNER JOIN tblRoleGrps rg ON ug.Grps = rg.Grps
GROUP BY ug.Usr, rg.Role
```

returning

```
Usr    Role   MatchCount
-----  -----  ----------
User1  Role1           2
User1  Role2           2
User1  Role3           1
User2  Role1           3
User2  Role2           2
User2  Role3           1
User3  Role1           1
User3  Role2           1
User3  Role3           2
User4  Role3           1
```

With these saved queries at our disposal we can build other queries to find matches between Users and Roles. For example, to list the instances where there is an "exact match", meaning...

> The number of matches between a User and a Role (qryUserRoleMatches.MatchCount) is exactly the number of Groups for that User (qryUsrGrpCounts.GrpCount) and exactly the number of Groups for the corresponding Role (qryRoleGrpCounts.GrpCount).

...we can use

```sql
SELECT qurm.Usr, qurm.Role
FROM
    (
        qryUsrRoleMatches qurm
        INNER JOIN
        qryUsrGrpCounts qugc
            ON qurm.Usr = qugc.Usr
                AND qurm.MatchCount = qugc.GrpCount
    )
    INNER JOIN
    qryRoleGrpCounts qrgc
        ON qurm.Role = qrgc.Role
            AND qurm.MatchCount = qrgc.GrpCount
```

returning

```
Usr    Role 
-----  -----
User1  Role2
User2  Role1
User3  Role3
```

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL ( SQL Sever) query can be written as:

```
with cte_servicecatalogue as
(
select sc1.UserId,
      STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + sc.Grps
                FROM servicecatalogue sc
                WHERE sc.UserId = sc1.UserId
                --GROUP BY sc.UserId
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), ''), 1, 2, '') [Groups]
from servicecatalogue sc1
GROUP BY sc1.UserId  
)
,cte_RoleMembership as
( select RM1.Role,
      STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + RM.Grps
                FROM RoleMembership RM
                WHERE RM.Role = RM1.Role
                --GROUP BY sc.UserId
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), ''), 1, 2, '') [Groups]
from RoleMembership RM1
GROUP BY RM1.Role  
)
select cte1.UserId, cte2.Role
from cte_servicecatalogue cte1
inner join cte_RoleMembership cte2 on cte1.[Groups] = cte2.[Groups]
order by UserId
```

check demo [here..](http://rextester.com/WTC15450)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this in detail in a moment but I can't see where you are preventing the results from including "subset" roles.

Comment: What I've done here is in first CTE I've grouped users and created a comma separated string of all the groups that the user belong to. Similarly in second CTE i've grouped roles and created a comma separated string of all the groups that the role contain. Then matched the two comma separted stinrgs to get desired result.

Comment: But the solution is in T-SQL and I've just checked the comments where you've mentioned you need solution in MS Access.

Comment: ...but it doesn't give the desired result surely as if a role is subset of another role then the user will appear as having both when we need the "biggest".

Comment: lets take an example you have Role 1 with group A,B,C and Role2 with group A,B ( means Role 2 is subset of Rule 1 ) now if a user say User 1 has only two groups say A,B then it belongs to subset ie Role2 but as soon as you will get one more entry like User1 --Group C the user will belong to Role1 that is the superset. Don't get confused.. even if you have entires like User1-GrpA, User1-GrpB, User1-GrpA,User1-GrpB,User1-GrpC.. the group by clause will take care of such multiple entries giving you result as User1-GrpA,GrpB,GrpC ie it qualifies for Role 1 and not Role2. Hope this helps!!!